# Performance: Native SVG elements or HTML elements in a <foreignObject>?

Tags: css, html, performance, browser, svg

I am writing a web app which renders a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) that holds ~700 nodes and their respective edges. Each node is displayed as a circle and inside of it is contained a block of text, a background image, as well as other content. The graph is interactive and the user can both scale and pan the graph. Thus smoothness and high performance is necessary.

Suppose the graph is rendered with SVG. Considering that each node contains rich HTML-like content, it is easier to structure and style the node with HTML/CSS in a `div` and include it in the graph as a foreignObject. However, with this method there is a noticible performance drop when using the app with mobile devices. Over a modern browser, would you expect a significant performance increase if nodes were structured purely in SVG?

In this particular case, using HTML for each node involves the use of a `div` with text, and CSS properties like `width`, `height`, `border`, `background-image`, `border-radius`, and `flex`.
Using pure SVG would be more complicated to implement, but would include elements like `rect` and `pattern` as well as the corresponding SVG styling attributes.

Comment: I'm aware there are other ways to optimize the rendering of hundreds of elements. I'd like to specifically address whether there's an inherent performance decrease when using embedded HTML and CSS styles as opposed to sticking with SVG elements and attributes.

Comment: On which mobile device? With which rendering engine? With what version of that engine? The question is broad and likely to go out of date as the rendering engine updates.

Comment: The question is still valid as an answer would illuminate the core mechanisms of how foreignObject/HTML in SVG renders on a low level, whether or not rendering engines change. And it's a worthwhile question as there are many reasons to opt for HTML/CSS in SVG vs straight SVG elements.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the complexity of the shapes, the size of the graph and how much time you want to put into it. A graph with 700 nodes and thousands of edges sure is a heavy thing. I would advise you to make a small version of the graph (maybe 10-15 nodes) and compare the performance between HTML+SVG and SVG only.

The thing is, using only SVG it is very heavy and not very performatic at all. I guess it'll be very heavy both ways. Have you considered using other tools?

I used [this website](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw3K2XBhAzEiwAmmgrAsuYAQpyKuZoQzouR_QLfH4ej_79C71grE2RERa6g88ttpiRMS_AexoCe_AQAvD_BwE) a while ago to make a flowchart for a website and it worked really well.

Hope it helps.